# Are there any JavaScript or CSS frameworks that add CSS3 support to IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Is there any JavaScript or CSS framework that adds CSS3 support to IE6, like html5shiv for HTML5 in IE6?

e.g: `filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#81a8cb', endColorstr='#4477a1');`

I found some filters but IE6 is getting hung by that code as the site has around 2000 lines of HTML code and 3000 lines of CSS code.

Comment: Why would you loose time and energy to support CSS3 on IE6 anyway...

Comment: I second that. Don't support IE6 or IE7. It's bad technology and a drain on the economy (as are IE8 and IE9 and probably any future version of IE10)

Comment: we all work for clients and some client still need support from IE6 to ipad :( sorry guys

Comment: People using IE6 already view a very crippled version of the Internet; they would not know the difference if your site was missing a few CSS3 features.   What if a client wanted support for IE 5.5?... simply explaining the cost/benefit ratio is the best way.   (cost= time, money, overhead; benefit= 1% of the audience) Some clients are ignorant about the limitations of technology and it's our job to educate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).